# Can I tell Ionic to work with master.zip on my PC?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and just I've started to learn it.
I have a question about 'ionic start' command. 
Why is it start to download master.zip from github? 
Can I save master.zip on my PC and tell ionic to read from it not downloading it every time for any new project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use your master.zip like:

```
ionic start myionicapp <full path of your master.zip>
```